# MySQL Table 'dbsql.cars' does not exist?

Tags: php, mysql

In my dbsql file, I have two CREATE TABLES the first works and the php associated with inserting values works as well.

Anyway, the second table doesn't work, any help is greatly appreciated, I will put the CREAT table statement, and then the PHP associated..

```
    CREATE TABLE `Cars` (
  `CarId` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `uploader` varchar(200) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_name),
  `DVLAMake` varchar(200) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `DVLAModel` varchar(200) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `BodyStyle` varchar(200) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `EngineSize` varchar(100) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `Year` varchar(200) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `Transmission` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `FuelType` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `CurrColour` varchar(50) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `NoOfDoors` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `SeatingCap` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `Length` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `Width` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `Height` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `CombEngCap` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `DriveType` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `MaxTorque` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci default '',
  `MaxPower` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci default '',
  `FuelConsumpURB` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci default '',
  `FuelConsumpCOMB` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci default '',
  `MaxSpeed` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci default '',
  `Acceleration` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci default '',
  `WeightKG` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci default '',
  `NCAPRating` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci default '',
  `SecRemCentLock` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `SecCentLock` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `SecAlarm` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `SecImmob` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `AudioEquip` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `ExtPowerAssSteer` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `ExtAssBreak` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `ExtElecWindows` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `ExtAirbags` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `ElecMirrors` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `ElecHeatedMir` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `IncWarranty` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `IncSerBook` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `IncMOT` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `IncPXConsid` ENUM('T','F') NOT NULL default 'F',
  `CurrColour` varchar(50) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `CarImage` varchar(50) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',

  PRIMARY KEY  (`CarId`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Car_search` (`DVLAMake`,`DVLAModel`,`BodyStyle`,`CurrColour`)
```

And here is the php: I haven't inserted the rest as it dies at the last line...

```
<?php
include 'dbc.php';


$path = "uploads/";

$path = $path . basename( $_FILES['imageUpload']['name']); 


/* mysql_connect("your.hostaddress.com", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 */
 //Writes the information to the database 



 $sql_insert = "INSERT into `Cars`
            (`CarImage`)
            VALUES
            ('$path')
            ";

mysql_query($sql_insert,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());

... ?>
```

Comment: the dbc.php has all the information for connecting, so ignore that. as the Users table works from the same system, I am lookingf or possible syntax errors with my table..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your create statement is wrong.
You use the same column name twice in your table: `CurrColour`

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated column CurrColumn then you miss a ) at the very end of the statement

Answer (score 0):

You have two entries of below column

```
`CurrColour` varchar(50) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
```